# Tool for managing testcases

Tags: software-development, project-management, software-testing

Is there a tool for managing testcases in large software projects?

Of course we could use a wiki or excel ;-) but for large projects a specialized software might fit better.

Features which may be supported:

- Suitable properties: Title, description, expected results, preconditions, ...
- Categorize testcases: Enduser tests, backend tests, system interface tests
- Multi user support: Some users write testcases, some users will do the actual tests.
- Status: Testcase is approved in version 1.2

Open source would be nice

OS: linux, windows

Comment: There isn't a single correct answer, you know :) For us the [TestLink](http://testlink.org/) was OK'ish. It should cover all your points, I reckon

Comment: OS: Linux and Windows vs. Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Checkpanel (https://checkpanel.com) is a free web application for managing recurring checks.

It is extremely easy to use and logs all test results for future reference. It has multi user support. You can define how often you want to test each item and be reminded of overdue tests.

It focuses a simple interface so it does not offer all of your requested properties. But you can probably achieve a similar structure by using separate lists and/or tags in titles. You will have to write down expected results and preconditions as part of the description.

Disclosure: I am the founder of Checkpanel.